# Why is switch over a string in android still not possible even with JDK7?

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-studio, java-7

I have a android project that is set up with gradle.

I use the following configuration:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

I thought that it is now possible to use Java 7 language features.
But when I try to use a switch-String statement I still get the error:

```
[...] found String, required: byte, char, short ,lon
```

So am I wrong here? Are the Java 7 language features still not available? What does the compileOptions mean then?

(I am using android studio 0.5.5)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a Java7 JDK in Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK location.

After you add the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` statements to your build.gradle file, you need to press the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button -- the IDE should have put a notification in the editor window if you made the edits from Android Studio.

When you re-sync the project, it should have given you the message that it needs to reload the project for the language level changes to take effect -- this is an IntelliJ limitation.

After I do that, it works for me.

Comment: That's pretty strange. The JDK location is correctly set to my jdk7 folder and I also do a sync very often because of dependency changes. I will give it another try.